# Using StateFlow in an Android Project

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Must be a very simple solution, but... 
I'm using `StateFlow` in my android project to replace `LiveData` that were used as Observables in a Service. I used LiveData as observables for `Room Database` but the limitations regarding thread (must register observer and notify on main thread) made me switch to `Flow` class. Everything fitted nicely and logically, and to keep info about state, I then decided to use `StateFlow`.

I added

> implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"

and

> ```
> tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
>     kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs += ["-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"]
> }
> ```

in my gradle file and

> @OptIn(kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)

on top of the classes that had StateFlow member types.
but I get a crash when I run the project stating:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lkotlinx/coroutines/flow/StateFlowKt;
>   ....
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowKt" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxxxx.consumer-X46raHzqXUeRRH40JT1LUg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xxxxx.consumer-X46raHzqXUeRRH40JT1LUg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.xxxxx.consumer-X46raHzqXUeRRH40JT1LUg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]] ....

What steps are necessary to add StateFlow in an Android Project using Kotlin?

Thanks!

Comment: I have just used `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.6`, without the rest of your changes. Are you using multiple modules? And, if so, did you perhaps put `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"` in a library module? If so, either perhaps that should be `api` or perhaps the app module should also have `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7"`.

Comment: Yes you were right, i have a library and i compile it as aar and then include that in a project using `debugImplementation files` on gradle (and releaseImplementation files). tried adding ..coroutine-core... at app module and worked! Thanks! (if you write your comment as anwer i'll accept that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple modules, and your library module using `StateFlow` apparently is not distributed via an artifact repository. As a result, the app module consuming that module is not getting transitive dependency data, so it has no way of knowing that your library module wants a particular version of coroutines.

IMHO, ideally, you would use an artifact repository (e.g., `mavenLocal()`) and have the library module use an `api` dependency for the coroutines library.

If you would prefer not to mess with that, any module consuming that library should also have the coroutines dependency, with a matching (or at least compatible) version.